# Trying to implement potential field navigation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, artificial-intelligence, planning

I am trying to produce an algorithm where multiple agents (blue) work together as a team to capture a slightly faster enemy agent (red) by preforming surrounding and circling tactics in a 2D grid. So I am trying to make a robust multi-agent algorithm that would allow multi-agents would capture an intelligent and faster enemy agent

So I attempted to give the enemy agent navigation and obstacle avoidance abilities by using something known as potential field navigation. Basically, the enemy agent pretends there is an attraction force at the exit and a repulsive force by each blue agent

[Click here for more details on potential fields](http://phoenix.goucher.edu/~jillz/cs325_robotics/goodrich_potential_fields.pdf)

When I implemented this into the enemy agent, the agent being attracted to the exit is successful (except for the fact it slows down when it is close to it). The main problem I am having is with the repulsion field where the enemy is trying to avoid the blue particles. While it attempts to escape, it does things such as moving in a zig-zag pattern rapidly, run around a blue particle or group or particles in circles.

I would like the enemy agent to smoothly avoid the blue particles in an intelligent way.

Also, is someone knows how to turn repulsive field into a tangential field, that would be great. I would like tangential fields so that the red particle can slip through the blue particles.

Also, although the code is long, the only function that the enemy agent uses is goToExit(), so that function and any function that it calls will be the only ones relevant.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from random import randint

import random
import math

keep = False
keepX = 0
keepY = 0

### Variables that we can play with ###
interestPointVisual = False
huntEnemy = True
numOfAgents = 10

enemyTopSpeed = 0.5
topSpeed = 0.3

secondDoor = False
resultVisual = False

#obstacleAvoidance = False
chargeEnemy = True

maxFrame = 2000

agentRadius = 2
####################################


phaseCount = 0

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(5, 4.5)

# Declaring the enemy and ally agents
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))
enemy = plt.Circle((10, -10), 0.95, fc='r')
agent = plt.Circle((10, -10), 0.95, fc='b')


if interestPointVisual:
    interestColor = 'y'
    interestSize = 0.55

else:
    interestColor = 'w'
    interestSize = 0.55
    #interestSize = 0.000001



midpoint = plt.Circle((10, -10), interestSize, fc=interestColor)

eastpoint = plt.Circle((10, -10), interestSize, fc=interestColor)
northpoint = plt.Circle((10, -10), interestSize, fc=interestColor)
westpoint = plt.Circle((10, -10), interestSize, fc=interestColor)


northeastpoint = plt.Circle((10, -10), interestSize, fc=interestColor)
mideastpoint = plt.Circle((10, -10), interestSize, fc=interestColor)
midwestpoint = plt.Circle((10, -10), interestSize, fc=interestColor)
northwestpoint = plt.Circle((10, -10), interestSize, fc=interestColor)

# Adding the exits
rect_size = 5
x_se_s = 47

x_se = 50
y_se = 0

southExit = plt.Rectangle([x_se_s - rect_size / 2, y_se - rect_size / 2], rect_size + 3, rect_size -2 , facecolor='black', edgecolor='black')

x_ne = 50
y_ne = 101

if secondDoor:
    northExit = plt.Rectangle([x_ne - rect_size / 2, y_ne - rect_size / 2], rect_size + 3, rect_size -2 , facecolor='black', edgecolor='black')


patches_ac = []

if interestPointVisual:
    ax.add_patch(midpoint)
    ax.add_patch(northpoint)
    ax.add_patch(eastpoint)
    ax.add_patch(westpoint)

    ax.add_patch(mideastpoint)
    ax.add_patch(midwestpoint)
    ax.add_patch(northeastpoint)
    ax.add_patch(northwestpoint)


# enemy, north, east, south, west
# 0 represents unoccupied, 1 represent occupied
global occupied_ar
global victory
global agentID
global timeStep

global agentLocationAR



ax.add_patch(agent)

for x in range(0, numOfAgents - 1):
    agent_clone = plt.Circle((10, -10), 0.95, fc='b')
    agent_clone.center = (random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100))
    patches_ac.append(agent_clone)
    ax.add_patch(agent_clone)

ax.add_patch(enemy)

# Adding exit patches
ax.add_patch(southExit)

if secondDoor:
    ax.add_patch(northExit)


def victoryCheck(enemy_patch):
    global agentLocationAR
    ex, ey = enemy_patch.center

    rangeVal = 0.8

    for i in range(0, numOfAgents-1):
        if abs(float(ex-agentLocationAR[i][0])) < rangeVal and  abs(float(ey-agentLocationAR[i][1])) < rangeVal:
            return True

    return False

def enemyWonCheck(enemy_patch):
    x,y = enemy_patch.center

    if (x > x_se - 4 and x < x_se + 4) and y <= y_se +4:
        return True
    return False

def borderCheck(x,y):

    if x < 0:
        x = 0

    elif x > 100:
        x = 100


    if y < 0:
        y = 0

    elif y > 100:
        y = 100


    return x, y


def init():
    global occupied_ar
    global agentLocationAR
    global keep
    global keepX
    global keepY

    keep = False
    keepX = 0
    keepY = 0

    #enemy.center = (50, 50)
    enemy.center = (random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(40, 100))
    agent.center = (random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100))

    occupied_ar = np.zeros([9])
    agentLocationAR = np.zeros((numOfAgents,2))


    for ac in patches_ac:
        ac.center = (random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100))





    return []

def animationManage(i):
    global occupied_ar
    global agentLocationAR
    global victory
    global agentID
    global timeStep
    global phaseCount
    global maxFrame

    timeStep = i


    agentID = 1
    followTarget(i, agent, enemy)

    agentLocationAR[agentID-1][0], agentLocationAR[agentID-1][1] = agent.center

    for ac in patches_ac:
        agentID = agentID + 1
        followTarget(i, ac, enemy)

        agentLocationAR[agentID-1][0], agentLocationAR[agentID-1][1] = ac.center




    goToExit(i, enemy, southExit)
    # printing tests


    if victoryCheck(enemy):
        print 'Phase ', phaseCount
        print 'Victory!'
        phaseCount += 1
        init()
    elif enemyWonCheck(enemy):
        print 'Phase ', phaseCount
        print 'Failure!'
        init()
    elif i >= maxFrame - 1:
        print 'Phase ', phaseCount
        phaseCount += 1



    return []


def goToExit(i, patch, exit_patch):
    global agentLocationAR
    global keep
    global keepX
    global keepY
    x, y = patch.center
    v_x, v_y = velocity_calc_exit(patch, exit_patch)

    mid_x, mid_y, rad_x, rad_y = getMidDistance(patch, exit_patch)
    rad_size = math.sqrt(rad_x**2 + rad_y**2)


    v_ax, v_ay = attractionFieldExit(patch, x_se, y_se)

    v_rx, v_ry = repulsiveFieldEnemy(patch, 5)

    v_x = v_ax + v_rx
    v_y = v_ay + v_ry
    '''
    if abs(v_rx) > 1:
        v_x = v_x/abs(v_x/10)
    if abs(v_ry) > 1:
        v_y = v_x/abs(v_x/10)
    '''
    # Nomalize the magnitude
    v_x = v_x*enemyTopSpeed*0.03
    v_y = v_y*enemyTopSpeed*0.03
    '''
    if abs(v_x) > 1 or abs(v_y) > 1:
        print '-------------'
        print 'Att X: ', v_ax
        print 'Att Y: ', v_ay
        print 'Rep X: ', v_rx
        print 'Rep Y: ', v_ry
        print 'Total X: ', v_x
        print 'Total Y: ', v_y
    '''


    # x position
    x += v_x*enemyTopSpeed

    # y position
    y += v_y*enemyTopSpeed

    x,y = borderCheck(x,y)

    patch.center = (x, y)


    return patch,

def dispersalCalc(user_patch):
    global agentLocationAR # we need location of agents
    for i in range(0,numOfAgents-1):
        if(checkSemiRadius(user_patch, agentRadius)):
            return True

    return False


def attractionFieldExit(user_patch, attr_x, attr_y):
    x,y = user_patch.center

    netX = (x - attr_x)
    netY = (y - attr_y)

    # To prevent slow down when enemy is close to exit
    if x - attr_x > 20 or y - attr_y > 20:
        if x - attr_x > 20:
            netX = (x - attr_x)
        else:
            if x - attr_x == 0:
                netX = 0
            else:
                netX = 5*((x - attr_x)/abs((x - attr_x)))



        if y - attr_y > 30:
            netY = (y - attr_y)
        else:
            if y -attr_y == 0:
                netY = 0
            else:
                netY = 50*((y - attr_y)/abs((y - attr_y)))
                #print 'something y ', netY


    return -netX, -netY

def repulsiveFieldEnemy(user_patch, repulseRadius):
    # repulsive field that will be used by the enemy agent
    global agentLocationAR
    x,y = user_patch.center
    totalRepX = 0
    totalRepY = 0

    scaleConstant = 1**38
    for i in range(0, numOfAgents-1):
        repX = 0
        repY = 0

        avoidX = agentLocationAR[i][0]
        avoidY = agentLocationAR[i][1]

        # To check if one of the agents to avoid are in range
        #print getDistanceScalar(x, y, avoidX, avoidY)
        if getDistanceScalar(x, y, avoidX, avoidY) <= repulseRadius:
            #print 'Enemy agent detected'
            netX = int(x - avoidX)
            netY = int(y - avoidY)

            # To deal with division by zero and normaize magnitude of repX and repY
            if netX == 0:
                netX = 0.2*((x - avoidX)/abs(x - avoidX))
            if netY == 0:
                netY = 0.2*((x - avoidX)/abs(x - avoidX))

            repX = ((1/abs(netX)) - (1/repulseRadius))*(netX/(abs(netX)**3))
            repY = ((1/abs(netY)) - (1/repulseRadius))*(netY/(abs(netY)**3))


        totalRepX = totalRepX + repX
        totalRepY = totalRepY + repY

    totalRepX = totalRepX/scaleConstant
    totalRepY = totalRepY/scaleConstant


    return -totalRepX, -totalRepY

def followTarget(i, patch, enemy_patch):
    x, y = patch.center

    # Will try to follow enemy
    #v_x, v_y = velocity_calc(patch, enemy_patch)

    # Will follow midpoint of enemy & exit
    v_x, v_y = velocity_calc_mid(patch, enemy_patch)  

    #print 'Here:'
    #print interest_ar


    # x position
    x += v_x

    # y position
    y += v_y

    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patches_ac


def getInterestPoints(enemy_patch, exit_patch):
    # Calculate interest points to attract agents

    x, y = enemy_patch.center

    # Calculate enemy-to-exit midpoint
    mid_x, mid_y, rad_x, rad_y = getMidDistance(enemy_patch, exit_patch)

    interest_ar = np.array([[x,y],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]])

    #north
    interest_ar[1][0] = x - rad_x
    interest_ar[1][1] = y - rad_y


    #east
    interest_ar[3][0] = x - rad_y
    interest_ar[3][1] = y + rad_x


    #south (basically the midpoint)
    interest_ar[5][0] = x + rad_x
    interest_ar[5][1] = y + rad_y


    #west
    interest_ar[7][0] = x + rad_y
    interest_ar[7][1] = y - rad_x




    # northeast
    interest_ar[2][0] = (interest_ar[1][0] + interest_ar[3][0])/2
    interest_ar[2][1] = (interest_ar[1][1] + interest_ar[3][1])/2

    #southeast
    interest_ar[4][0] = (interest_ar[3][0] + interest_ar[5][0])/2
    interest_ar[4][1] = (interest_ar[3][1] + interest_ar[5][1])/2

    #southwest
    interest_ar[6][0] = (interest_ar[5][0] + interest_ar[7][0])/2
    interest_ar[6][1] = (interest_ar[5][1] + interest_ar[7][1])/2

    interest_ar[8][0] = (interest_ar[7][0] + interest_ar[1][0])/2
    interest_ar[8][1] = (interest_ar[7][1] + interest_ar[1][1])/2


    # Setting up visuals
    northpoint.center = (interest_ar[1][0], interest_ar[1][1])
    eastpoint.center = (interest_ar[3][0], interest_ar[3][1])
    midpoint.center = (interest_ar[5][0], interest_ar[5][1])
    westpoint.center = (interest_ar[7][0], interest_ar[7][1])

    mideastpoint.center = (interest_ar[2][0], interest_ar[2][1])
    midwestpoint.center = (interest_ar[4][0], interest_ar[4][1])
    northeastpoint.center = (interest_ar[6][0], interest_ar[6][1])
    northwestpoint.center = (interest_ar[8][0], interest_ar[8][1])


    return interest_ar


def findClosestInterest(agent_patch, in_ar):
    # For some reason, north never gets occupied

    # north east is (north/2) + (south/2)
    global occupied_ar
    global victory
    global agentID
    global timeStep
    global huntEnemy


    victory = False

    index = -1
    smallDis = 999999


    tempAr = np.zeros([9])

    if huntEnemy:
        minDis = 0
    else:
        minDis = 1

    # To check agent's distance of all interest points
    for i in range(minDis,9):
        dis = abs(int(getDistance(agent_patch, in_ar, i)))


       # Add heavy weights to charge at enemy
        if chargeEnemy:
            if i == 0:
                dis = dis*0.5



        if occupied_ar[i] != 0:
            # we must write a condition so that agent knows it is the
            # one that is occupying it
            dis = dis*5

        # Add heavy weights to avoid the back
        if i == 1 or i == 8 or i == 2:

            if i == 1:
                dis = dis*3
            elif i == 2 or i == 8:
                dis = dis*4


        tempAr[i] = dis




        # When we discover unoccupied shorter distance, replace index        
        if dis < smallDis:

            # index is agent_patch.center[0] < 47 and agent_patch.center[0] > 53the index of interest_array of the closest interest point 
            smallDis = dis
            index = i

    # If the smallest distance is less than 10, we are currently engaged


    if smallDis < 0.5:
        # We are near or at the targeted interest point,
        # now we should update array as occupied


        occupied_ar[index] = agentID

        if occupied_ar[0] != 0:
            victory = True

        #print 'engaged index ', index
    else:
        # Else we are still far away from the index
        if occupied_ar[index] == agentID:
            occupied_ar[index] = 0


            #print 'lost track of index ', index
        #else:
            #print 'far away from index ', index


    return index

def getBypassInterestPoints(user_patch,avoidX, avoidY, exit_x, exit_y):
    # Mainly used by the enemy agent
    # User agent will find a point around the blocking agent that is closest to
    # the exit.
    x,y = user_patch.center
    rad_range = 20

    tempX = x - avoidX
    tempY = y - avoidY

    diffR = math.sqrt(tempX**2 + tempY**2)

    # Calculating our target x and y length
    radX = (rad_range*tempX)/diffR
    radY = (rad_range*tempY)/diffR

    # Now we calculate the main interest points

    # Since we are calculating perpendicular points, we reverse the X and Y
    # in the pt calculation process
    pt1X = avoidX + radY
    pt1Y = avoidY - radX

    ###
    pt2X = avoidX - radY
    pt2Y = avoidY + radX

    # Then we must determine which interest point is closer to the exit

    pt1Dis = int(getDistanceScalar(pt1X, pt1Y,exit_x, exit_y))
    pt2Dis = int(getDistanceScalar(pt2X, pt2Y,exit_x, exit_y))

    # If point 1 is closer to the exit than point 2
    if(int(pt1Dis) <= int(pt2Dis)):
        print int(pt1X)
        return pt1X, pt1Y

    print int(pt2X)
    return int(pt2X), int(pt2Y)


def getDistanceScalar(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)

def getDistance(agent_patch, in_ar, index):
    x_a, y_a = agent_patch.center
    x_t = in_ar[index][0]
    y_t = in_ar[index][1]


    # get distance between two particles
    ans = math.sqrt((x_t - x_a)**2 + (y_t - y_a)**2)
    if math.isnan(ans):
        print 'x_a: ',x_a
        print 'y_a: ',y_a
        print 'x_t: ',x_t
        print 'y_t: ',y_t
        init()
    return math.sqrt((x_t - x_a)**2 + (y_t - y_a)**2)


def getMidDistance(enemy_patch, exit_patch):
    # Get midpoint between enemy agent and exit

    x, y = enemy_patch.center
    x_e = x_se
    y_e = y_se

    # Get midpoint values
    mid_x = (x + x_e)/2
    mid_y = (y + y_e)/2

    # Get radius values
    rad_x = mid_x - x
    rad_y = mid_y - y

    # Returns (midpoint x and y) values and (radius x and y) values
    return mid_x, mid_y, rad_x, rad_y

def top_speed_regulate(curr_speed, top_speed):

    if curr_speed > top_speed:
        return top_speed
    elif curr_speed < -top_speed:
        return -top_speed
    else:
        return curr_speed

def velocityCalcScalar(x1, y1, x2, y2):

    veloX = top_speed_regulate( (x2 - x1)      ,enemyTopSpeed)
    veloY = top_speed_regulate( (y2 - y1)      ,enemyTopSpeed)

    return veloX, veloY


# Calculate velocity to rush to exit
def velocity_calc_exit(agent_patch, exit_patch):

    x, y = agent_patch.center
    #x_e, y_e = exit_patch.center
    x_e = x_se
    y_e = y_se

    velo_vect = np.array([0.0, 0.0], dtype='f')

    dis_limit_thresh = 1 



    velo_vect[0] = top_speed_regulate( (x_e - x)* dis_limit_thresh    ,enemyTopSpeed)
    velo_vect[1] = top_speed_regulate( (y_e - y)* dis_limit_thresh    ,enemyTopSpeed)

    return velo_vect[0], velo_vect[1]


# Calculate velocity to chase down enemy
def velocity_calc(agent_patch, enemy_patch):

    x, y = agent_patch.center
    x_e, y_e = enemy_patch.center

    velo_vect = np.array([0.0, 0.0], dtype='f')

    dis_limit_thresh = 1 



    velo_vect[0] = top_speed_regulate( (x_e - x)* dis_limit_thresh    ,topSpeed)
    velo_vect[1] = top_speed_regulate( (y_e - y)* dis_limit_thresh    ,topSpeed)

    return velo_vect[0], velo_vect[1]

# Calculate velocity to arrive at midpoint between enemy and exit
def velocity_calc_mid(agent_patch, enemy_patch):


    x, y = agent_patch.center
    x_e, y_e, _, _ = getMidDistance(enemy_patch, southExit)

    # We get location of interest points as well as animate the interest points
    interest_ar = getInterestPoints(enemy_patch, southExit)

    interest_index = findClosestInterest(agent_patch, interest_ar)




    x_e = interest_ar[interest_index][0]
    y_e = interest_ar[interest_index][1]




    velo_vect = np.array([0.0, 0.0], dtype='f')

    dis_limit_thresh = 1 

    topSpeed = 0.3

    velo_vect[0] = top_speed_regulate( (x_e - x)* dis_limit_thresh    , topSpeed)
    velo_vect[1] = top_speed_regulate( (y_e - y)* dis_limit_thresh    , topSpeed)

    '''
    if dispersalCalc(agent_patch):
        velo_vect[0] = 0
        velo_vect[1] = 0
    '''
    return velo_vect[0], velo_vect[1]


def checkRadius(user_patch, r):
    global agentLocationAR
    r = 1
    for i in range(0,numOfAgents-1):
        x = int(agentLocationAR[i][0])
        y = int(agentLocationAR[i][1])

        if(inRadius(user_patch, x, y, r)):
            # if an agent is in the user's radius
            #print 'Nearby agent detected'
            return True


    return False

def checkSemiRadius(user_patch, r):
    global agentLocationAR
    r = 0.001
    for i in range(0,numOfAgents-1):
        x = int(agentLocationAR[i][0])
        y = int(agentLocationAR[i][1])

        if(inSemiRadius(user_patch, x, y, r)):
            # if an agent is in the user's radius
            #print 'Nearby agent detected'
            return True


    return False


def inRadius(self_patch, pointX, pointY, r):
    # Helps determine if there is something near the using agent

    x, y = self_patch.center # agent emitting the radius
    # agent we are trying to avoid

    h = pointX
    k = pointY    
    # Equation of circle
    # (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 <= r^2

    tempX = (x - h)**2
    tempY = (y - k)**2

    r_2 = r**2

    if tempX + tempY <= r_2:
        # It is within the radius
        return True
    else:
        return False


def inSemiRadius(self_patch, pointX, pointY, r):
    # Helps determine if there is something near the using agent

    h, k = self_patch.center # agent emitting the radius
    # agent we are trying to avoid
    x = pointX
    y = pointY
    # Equation of semicircle

    tempTerm = r**2 - (x-h)**2

    if tempTerm < 0:
        # if this term is negative, that means agent to avoid is out of range
        return False

    tempEq = k - math.sqrt(tempTerm)


    if y <= tempEq:
        # It is within the radius
        return True
    else:
        return False



def animateCos(i, patch):
    x, y = patch.center
    x += 0.1

    y = 50 + 30 * np.cos(np.radians(i))
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animationManage,
                               init_func=init,
                               frames=maxFrame,
                               interval=1,
                               blit=True,
                               repeat=True)


plt.show()
```

Comment: From reading the journal article that you mention (and without going into the specifics of the code), it looks like what you'd like to do is have the red agent consider the blue agents as obstacles, not repulsive fields. Indeed, treating the Exit as an attraction field, and the blue agents as a repulsive field, is very likely to result into local random fields, which would in turn make the red agent zig-zag in circles.

In contrast, treating the blue agents as obstacles will steer the red agent away from them, without "distracting" it from the Exit attraction field.

Comment: From what I understood, you would place repulsive fields (perhaps even tangential fields) around obstacles in order for an agent to move away from an obstacle. If that is not the case, how would I get the red agent to treat the blue agents like obstacles then?

Comment: I realized I phrased my comment wrong, and I'm also not an expert in this, so maybe my suggestion is misguided. What I meant is that if the red agent stop moving toward the exit and instead prioritize avoiding the blue agent, it must be that the relative strength of the avoidance/attraction fields is miscalibrated. You want the red agent to try to escape only if a blue agent comes within its immediate vicinity (very weak repulsive field) but to always move toward the Exit (strong attraction field).

Comment: I tried to lower the strength of the repulsive field, but the red agent still produces a zig-zag like pattern (except smaller) and sometimes even fail to try to get out of the way and stand in place as the blue agents capture the red agent.

Comment: In addition, your suggestion would not work if the blue agent is directly in between the red agent and the exit if we are using repulsive fields (because of the vector field shape of repulsive fields). I feel like tangential potential fields would be a better solution, but I don't know the equation of the tangential potential field's gradient.